# DataAnnotation to modify serialized JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way add a data attribute to a property and have it effect the json serializer to add a function call around the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't an easy way to control the json serialization process especially with things like adding function calls around some properties which could result into an invalid JSON. But if you are trying to return JSONP you could [write a custom JsonpResult](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/entry-EnablingJSONPcallsonASPNETMVC.aspx).

Comment: Although I didn't end up going with this solution, i found that the ko.mapping plugin does what i need it on the client side.  I like your solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about an action filter that looks for JSON results and modifies them. It might be a two step process:

- on action executing: check for the attribute and set a flag if you find it
- on action execute: if the flag has been set, tart up the result.

I am not confident about this btw :P